# Does future::wait() synchronize-with completion of the thread of execution by async()?

Tags: c++, c++11, synchronization, atomic, memory-model

It's said that [`thread::join()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) synchronizes-with completion of the corresponding thread of execution. I'm wondering whether the same applies to `async()` and `future::wait()`. So for example:

```cpp
std::atomic_int v(0);
std::async(
  std::launch::async,
  [&v] { v.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); }
).wait();
assert(v.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) == 1);
```

The `assert()` will never fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Straight from N3337 ([c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) standard draft), [[futures.async]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/futures.async#5) with my emphasis:

> *Synchronization*: Regardless of the provided policy argument,
>
> - the invocation of async synchronizes with ([intro.multithread]) the invocation of f. [ Note: This statement applies even when the
>     corresponding future object is moved to another thread.  — end note ];
>     and
> - **the completion of the function f is sequenced before** ([intro.multithread]) **the shared state is made ready**. [ Note: f might
>     not be called at all, so its completion might never happen.  — end
>     note ]
>
> If the implementation chooses the `launch::async` policy,
>
> - **a call to a waiting function on an asynchronous return object that shares the shared state created by this async call shall block until
>     the associated thread has completed, as if joined**
>     ([thread.thread.member]);
> - the associated thread completion synchronizes with ([intro.multithread]) the return from the first function that
>     successfully detects the ready status of the shared state or with the
>     return from the last function that releases the shared state,
>     whichever happens first.

So referring to your question this means that yes, the assertion will never fail.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to standard. Based on common sense, I think this got to be true. Now, I'm sure of it :)